# Transpose dataframe in R with difference lenghts

Tags: r

Is there a way to transpose dataframe in R as shown below. The transpose here is little tricky and hence asking for help

```
asd <- data.frame(a = c("A","A", "B", "C"), Time = c(1,2,3,4), c = c(4,7,8,9))
```

Expected output

```
Time  A   B   C
 1    4   NA  NA
 2    7   NA  NA
 3    NA  8   9
 4    NA  3   4
```

Comment: Try `tidyr::pivot_wider(asd, names_from = a, values_from = c)`

Answer (score -1):

```
asd <- data.frame(a = c("A","A", "B", "C"), Time = c(1,2,3,4), c = c(4,7,8,9))
```